# Referencing different stylesheets in different views in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sprockets

I want to have a different set of stylesheets for the different parts of my Rails application. For example, I want to have a set of stylesheets for the landing page, a different set for the backend `admin` pages, and another set for the logged in `account` pages.

I've organized the stylesheets into folders with the names account, home, and admin, and I know how to specify in the application.css to just compile one folder.

```
*= require_self
*= require_tree ./account
*/
```

My question is, how do I specify that if the user is viewing the admin pages, or the home pages that the stylesheets in the admin or home folder should be the only style sheets that are referenced?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no way to create conditonal stylesheet creation, because on production it is compiled on deployment.

You must create separate stylesheets, for example one would be default application.css:

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require some_stylesheet
*/
```

Then separate, admin.css

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require some_admin_stylesheet
*/
```

Then in production enviroment configuration extend line:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['application.css', 'admin.css']
```

Next, create separate layout/or create conditional inclusion of:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "admin" %>
```

Comment: So the best way to separate my app into these separate sections is to create separate layout files and top level stylesheets for each section? That doesn't seem very DRY.

Comment: You can skip layouts, just create conditional inclusion of stylesheets based on controller or whatever you want... but you can't put conditions on manifest file.

Comment: If you want, instead of adding the file to every environment you can add this line `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ['admin.css']` into the `config/initializers/assets.rb` and you are done. (Rails 4.2.5)